# Why is protractor 'EC.elementToBeClickable' not implemented as it declares to be?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have a element (button 'che-in/boarding pass') that class is 'disabled' at first, then enabled after another element (button 'check eligibility') is clicked. Please refer to the screenshots.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

My protractor test step is:

1) click 'check eligibility' button, and then

2) click 'check-in / boarding pass' button

And i am using standard wait function before clicking 'check-in / boarding pass' button, like:

```
var elm = element(by.id('xxxxxx'));
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elm), 5000);
elm.click();
```

But it does work at all. it's giving error 'WebDriverError: unknown error: Element xxx is not clickable at point (759, 725). Other element would receive the click'

Then i go to check the definition of 'EC.elementToBeClickable', it says,

```
 /**
 * An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you
 * can click it.
 *
 * @example
 * var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
 * // Waits for the element with id 'abc' to be clickable.
 * browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable($('#abc')), 5000);
 *
 * @alias ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable
 * @param {!ElementFinder} elementFinder The element to check
 *
 * @returns {!function} An expected condition that returns a promise
 *     representing whether the element is clickable.
 */
elementToBeClickable(elementFinder: ElementFinder): Function;
```

which specifically says it will check if element is 'visible and enabled'. Then why is my code snippet not working?

P.S.

1. The element locator I use is correct, because if I add a hard coded wait of 5sec before clicking first button and second button, then everything works
2. elementToBeClickable() does not seem to wait at all. it throw error almost immediately.

Comment: Is it possible you have some other dynamic content that loads and changes the layout of the DOM, and therefore changes the location of that element?

Comment: @KyleLussier I am using the locator of the 2nd button after its class is changed. what i observe is that the wait.elementToBeClickable() call returns so quickly that i can not visually see the 2nd button enabled. but is it possible that during certain time, the 'disabled' class of 2nd element is already gone but it is still visually block by dynamic content being loaded? If so, what can i do?

Comment: On second thought, the issue could be that you are using a class to "disable" the button, while not actually setting the disabled attribute on the button. So technically the button is visible and the button is enabled according to protractor/selenium. Perhaps one solution would be to wait until the "disabled" class has been removed, and then try clicking the button.

Comment: @KyleLussier thanks, kyle. you're right. it works.

Comment: FWIW, [images are not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).  Much easier for everyone if you just describe your problem with a basic sample of the code https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you issue related to how Selenium determine an element is enable or disable. According to WebDriver W3C Sepcification I found Selenium use below rules to determine element is enable or disable.

Your button use CSS `pointer-events: none` to archive disable effect which Selenium not take it into calculation logic.

Actually, you can try to get the `disabled` attribute of your button, it will be `false` event you can't click on it.  I think Selenium use the `disabled` attribute as the result of element enabled or not.

So you need to wait the CSS value of `pointer-events` is not `none`, rather than call `EC.elementToBeClickable`

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks, yong. Kyle's answer works. but yours is pointing to right direction as well.